# Unparseable Date " " for empty Date value

Tags: groovy, java.util.date

Basically I have a function which gets multiple JSON Objects, the objects are defined as property in someVO file, the code looks like this:

```
protected def createTheObject(JSONObject obj) {
new someVO {
  property1: obj.get("property1"),
  property2: obj.get("property2"),
  dateprop: CustomDatePropertyEditor.getDateFormat().parse(obj?.get('dateprop') as String),
  }}
```

As the casting exception occured while converting String to Date, I've added getDateFormat() function specifically.
property1, property2 are String type data, while dateProp is Date type data.

If by chance the dateprop is null value I'm getting a runtime error:
Unparseable Date " "

Can anyone help me on that?

Comment: Help you how? It's an unparseable date. Either don't parse it, or do something to insert a default parseable date.

Comment: I only want to unparse it for null date, so how do I change the syntactic code, using ternary operator is giving me some other issues, only way is to further append this line of code to something useful.